# Elite Dangerous - Combat Logging

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

Is it still possible to combat log in the open world PVP side of the game? I noticed in the latest patch that they essentially added galaxy wide bounties, which is a great change. Would still be quite useless if players are still abusing the combat logging, has that ever been addressed?

Combat logging was when a player would hit ALT + F4 to quickly log out of the game just before death. It used to immediately despawn your ship, thus saving it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is still possible.

It's considered cheating and a pattern of it can get you shadowbanned, especially if your opponents report it.

The peer to peer nature of the game means it is very unlikely that they will ever be able to prevent combat logging. There have been discussions of methods of automatically punishing combat logging, but none of those would apply to a single time doing it (since it's entirely possible to crash or lose your internet mid-combat).

Comment: It definitively something the FDEV team are looking at curbing, but it's a multi-faceted issue, and is not going away soon.